# How to print elements from another function into main function

Tags: arrays, c, function

I can't figure out how to print array elements from my function into the main program so if some can examine this code and help me fix it I would appreciate it. The program is supposed to take the length of the array from user input and then ask for its elements and print them out afterward.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int arrayN(int N) {
    printf("Input array lenght: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    
    if(N>2) {
        return N;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int arrayelements(int array[], int array_length) {
    int loop, i, N;
    
    array_length = arrayN(N);
    
    printf("Enter elements of the array: \n");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    
    for(loop = 0; loop < array_length; loop++) {
        printf("%d ", array[loop]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int N, array[], array_length;
    int b = arrayelements(array[], array_length);
    int a = arrayN(N);
    
    printf("Array length is: %d \n", a);
    printf("Elements of array are: %d \n", b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An array after being defined does not ever change its size; it cannot be able to hold 10 elements at line 42... and large enough for 1000 elements at line 52. Also `int array[];` does not specify a size and is not valid.

Comment: You should read about dynamic memory allocation using `malloc` in your C text book.

Comment: I believe that your code does not compile, due to this: `int b = arrayelements( ->array[]<-, array_length);`. Please fix your code until it does and then post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked your example code. Hope it is what you want.

Focus lied on fixing the array declaration issues, memory allocation and
user input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int userinput_integer(const char *fmt, ...){
    int N, rv = 0;
    va_list va;
    
    va_start(va, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, va);
    
    while(1){
        rv = scanf("%d", &N);
        if (1 == rv) break;
        
        printf("Input error! The input >>");
        do{
            rv = fgetc(stdin);
            if (isprint(rv)) putchar(rv);
        }while(rv != EOF && rv != '\n');
        
        printf("<< is not a valid integer.\nPlease try again: ");
    }
    
    va_end(va);
    return N;
}

int userinput_arraylength(void) {
    int N;
    
    N = userinput_integer("Input array lenght: ");
    
    if(N>2) {
        return N;
    } else {
        printf("Invalid length\n");
        
        return 0;
    }
}

int userinput_arrayelements(int *array, int N) {
    printf("Enter elements of the array: \n");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        array[i] = userinput_integer("%d: ", i);
    }

    return N;
}

void print_arrayelements(int *array, int N){
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int N, *array;
       
    N = userinput_arraylength();
    array = malloc(N * sizeof(*array));
    if (NULL == array){
        printf("Allocation error!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    N = userinput_arrayelements(array, N);
    
    printf("Array length is: %d \n", N);
    printf("Elements of array are:\n");
    print_arrayelements(array, N);
    
    free(array);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fistly, declaration of array is not correct.
It should be array[] = {0}

Secondly, you cannot call your array elements function before arrayN function, the size of array should be entered first

And in the array elements() there is no need to call the size function you can directly pass the size of array when calling the array elements ()

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include<malloc.h>  
int *getarray()  
{  
    int size;  
    printf("Enter the size of the array : ");  
    scanf("%d",&size);  
    int *p= malloc(sizeof(size));  
    printf("\nEnter the elements in an array");  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
    {  
        scanf("%d",&p[i]);  
    }  
    return p;  
}  
int main()  
{  
   int *ptr;  
   ptr=getarray();  
   int length=sizeof(*ptr);  
   printf("Elements that you have entered are : ");  
    for(int i=0;ptr[i]!='\0';i++)  
    {  
      printf("%d ", ptr[i]);  
    }  
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: The answer is wrong in several points: 1.) Declaration of ptr as int* but comparison with '\0', 2.) length is NOT the length of the array it is of sizeof(int), 3.) The malloc does not take into account the array element size nor the element count and allocates space for only one int. 4.) length is defined but not used 5.) The pointer from getarray does not point to an array with a zero last element etc...